# Tokenizing a huge quantity of text in python

Tags: python, string, nlp, tokenize

I have a huge list of text files to tokenize. I have the following code which works for a small dataset.  I am having trouble using the same procedure with a huge dataset, however. I am giving the example of a small dataset as below.

```
In [1]: text = [["It works"], ["This is not good"]]

In [2]: tokens = [(A.lower().replace('.', '').split(' ') for A in L) for L in text]

In [3]: tokens
Out [3]: 
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f67c2a703c0>,
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f67c2a70320>]

In [4]: list_tokens = [tokens[i].next() for i in range(len(tokens))]
In [5]: list_tokens
Out [5]:
[['it', 'works'], ['this', 'is', 'not', 'good']]
```

While all works so well with a small dataset, I encounter problem processing a huge list of lists of strings (more than 1,000,000 lists of strings) with the same code. As I still can tokenize the strings with the huge dataset as in `In [3]`, it fails in `In [4]` (i.e. killed in terminal).  I suspect it is just because the body of the text is too big.

I am here, therefore, seek for suggestions on the improvement of the procedure to obtain lists of strings in a list as what I have in `In [5]`.

My actual purpose, however, is to count the words in each list. For instance, in the example of the small dataset above, I will have things as below.

```
[[0,0,1,0,0,1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]] (note: each integer denotes the count of each word)
```

If I don't have to convert generators to lists to get the desired results (i.e. word counts), that would also be good.

Please let me know if my question is unclear. I would love to clarify as best as I can. Thank you.

Comment: I would use a `set()` to build the original list of all words in all strings, and then iterate through that with a count to generate the table of values.

Comment: How much RAM does your computer have? Also, I suppose your dataset is stored in a file, can you load it sentence by sentence? You will save a lot of memory that way

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `set` of unique words, then loop through and count each of those...

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

text = [["It works works"], ["It is not good this"]]

SplitList   = [x[0].split(" ") for x in text]
FlattenList = sum(SplitList,[])  # "trick" to flatten a list
UniqueList  = list(set(FlattenList))
CountMatrix = [[x.count(y) for y in UniqueList] for x in SplitList]

print UniqueList
print CountMatrix
```

Output is the total list of words, and their counts in each string:

```
['good', 'this', 'is', 'It', 'not', 'works']
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: I am sorry. I did not see that the text you used was different. So you are actually right. Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Sure. I just changed the text to make sure it worked with repeated words.

Comment: As I tried your code with my huge dataset, the process is still killed in the terminal. Nevertheless, I still appreciate your input. The code is beautiful.

Comment: There are probably linguistics  libraries for this purpose. Maybe someone else will have a suggestion.

Comment: For whatever approach, if your input text is huge it will take a long time/memory. You might want to try splitting the text and using multiple threads to process each chunk in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of available tokenizers that are optimized.  I would look at `CountVectorizer` in `sklearn`, which is built for counting tokens.

Update September 2019:
Use spaCy.

Comment: Thank you. I used CountVectorizer. While I attempted to transform the raw text to count data, however, I ran out of memory. Here is my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670059/vectorization-in-sklearn-seems-to-be-very-memory-expensive-why   I will try textblob. I did not know this option before. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Try poking around in `gensim`.  That package is written to avoid using much RAM.  You can work with files saved on disk (as opposed to loading them into memory).  I'm pretty sure `gensim` has a tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned it is huge dataset. use this

```
In [1]: text = [["It works"], ["This is not good"]]

IN [2]:

processed_features = []

for sentence in range(0, len(text )):
   # remove all single characters
   processed_feature= re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', processed_feature)

   # Converting to Lowercase
   processed_feature = processed_feature.lower()

   processed_features.append(processed_feature)

processed_features

#['it works', 'this is not good']

IN [3]:

import nltk
new_contents = []
for i in range(0, len(processed_features)):
    new_content = nltk.tokenize.TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize(processed_features[i])
    new_contents.append(new_content)

new_contents 

#[['it', 'works'], ['this', 'is', 'not', 'good']
```