# Vectorization in sklearn seems to be very memory expensive. Why?

Tags: memory-management, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I need to process more than 1,000,000 text records. I am employing CountVectorizer to transform my data. I have the following code.

```
TEXT = [data[i].values()[3] for i in range(len(data))] #these are the text records

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(TEXT)


X_list = X.toarray().tolist()
```

As I run this code, it turns out `MemoryError`.  The text records I have are mostly in short paragraphs (~100 words).  Vectorization seems to be very expensive.

**UPDATE**

I added more constraints to CountVectorizer but still got MemoeryError. The length of `feature_names` is 2391.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=0.003,max_df = 3.05, lowercase = True, stop_words = 'english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(TEXT)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

X_tolist = X.toarray().tolist()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nlp2.py", line 42, in <module>
X_tolist = X.toarray().tolist()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 940, in toarray
return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 250, in toarray
B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 817, in _process_toarray_args
return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

Why is so and how to get around with it? Thank you!!

Comment: Can you give us access to your data set? Also, which line is the MemoryError on? Can you give us the trace?

Comment: Thanks bpachev, I don't know how to give you access to the data set as it is in a remote server with security. The MemoryError comes only when I execute `X_list = X.toarray().tolist()` I was told to set min and max_df. I only had min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that X is a **sparse matrix** with one row for each document representing which words are present in that document. If you have a million documents with a total of 2391 distinct words in all (length of feature_names as provided in your question), the total number of entries in the dense version of x would be about **two billion**, enough to potentially cause a memory error.

The problem is with this line `X_list = X.toarray().tolist()` which converts X to a dense array. You don't have enough memory for that, and there should be a way to do what you are trying to do without it, (as the sparse version of X has all the information that you need.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed the case. The sparse version of X has all the information that I need -- I had been converting whenever I needed to fit a model and finally realized it's not necessary. Learned it in a hard way.